# In Google Sheets, I'm trying to create a drop down that reads from 2 columns but returns from 1 column

Tags: google-sheets, data-validation, vlookup

Basically, I have store number and Store name. I want to be able to start typing a name and select the name, but only show the store number.

If that is not possible, then I thought I can combine store number "-" name and then upon selection i should be able to Lens to the before "-".

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Data validation drop drowns in Google Sheets can't pull data from two columns.

One solution is the one that you already figured out, join the values of those columns and the use those joined values.